# I got the cookie but am not able to log in with them. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, dom, cookies

I don't remember password of the email account in my office (so my superior do). I said him 'no problemo' and saved the cookie, to open the same account at home, but now the browser seem to disagree with me when I try to equal document.cookie with the cookie I saved as a string. It set the cookie default every time.
What me to do to open that account?

Comment: .... Are you asking us to help you crack the security of your company? There's more to cookies than just `document.cookie`. You may want to read [MDN's article on cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies).

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are valid only for a session, not for the lifetime of the account. If your account auto-logs out after say 20 minutes, the cookie is meaningless after that. Cookies are so that you don't have to relogin for every single request within that time span.

Comment: 1) I had not stopped session yet manually. Does mail logs it out by itself in the background?

Comment: 2) And what for hackers steal cookies if it is not possible to use?